# Simplify MySQL INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to simplify the code below?  I want to simplify it, but I don't know if it is possible.

In the table below, I insert data which will end up in a MySQL table.

HTML

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Dată / Interval orar</td>
        <td align="center">Denumire</td>
        <td align="center">Moderatori</td>
        <td align="center">Detalii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input name="DataInterval1" type="text" id="DataInterval1"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Denumire1" type="text" id="Denumire1"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Moderatori1" type="text" id="Moderatori1"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Detalii1" type="text" id="Detalii1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input name="DataInterval2" type="text" id="DataInterval2"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Denumire2" type="text" id="Denumire2"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Moderatori2" type="text" id="Moderatori2"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Detalii2" type="text" id="Detalii2"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input name="DataIntervaln" type="text" id="DataIntervaln"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Denumiren" type="text" id="Denumiren"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Moderatorin" type="text" id="Moderatorin"></td>
        <td align="center"><input name="Detaliin" type="text" id="Detaliin"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Part of the PHP code that I want to simplify:

```
$DataInterval1=$_POST['DataInterval1'];
$Denumire1=$_POST['Denumire1'];
$Moderatori1=$_POST['Moderatori1'];
$Detalii1=$_POST['Detalii1'];   
$DataInterval2=$_POST['DataInterval2'];
$Denumire2=$_POST['Denumire2'];
$Moderatori2=$_POST['Moderatori2'];
$Detalii2=$_POST['Detalii2'];
...
$DataIntervaln=$_POST['DataIntervaln'];
$Denumiren=$_POST['Denumiren'];
$Moderatorin=$_POST['Moderatorin'];
$Detaliin=$_POST['Detaliin'];   

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO tabel (DataInterval, Denumire, Moderatori, Detalii)VALUES
('".$DataInterval1."', '".$Denumire1."', '".$Moderatori1."', '".$Detalii1."'),
('".$DataInterval2."', '".$Denumire2."', '".$Moderatori2."', '".$Detalii2."'),
... 
('".$DataIntervaln."', '".$Denumiren."', '".$Moderatorin."', '".$Detaliin."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: The mysql extension has been deprecated; no longer in active development, and no longer supported in php5.5x. Using the old mysql extension will make your code less future proof. Look into PDO and mysqli (-mysql "improved" extension) and also take advantage of their support for OOP.

Answer (score 1):

### Use indexing in HTML name attributes

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Dată / Interval orar</td>
        <td>Denumire</td>
        <td>Moderatori</td>
        <td>Detalii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="DataInterval[0]" type="text" id="DataInterval1"></td>
        <td><input name="Denumire[0]" type="text" id="Denumire1"></td>
        <td><input name="Moderatori[0]" type="text" id="Moderatori1"></td>
        <td><input name="Detalii[0]" type="text" id="Detalii1"></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td><input name="DataInterval[n]" type="text" id="DataIntervaln"></td>
        <td><input name="Denumire[n]" type="text" id="Denumiren"></td>
        <td><input name="Moderatori[n]" type="text" id="Moderatorin"></td>
        <td><input name="Detalii[n]" type="text" id="Detaliin"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Use the indexing on the server side

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST["DataInterval"] as $index => $value) {
    $data[] = array(
        "DataInterval" => $_POST["DataInterval"][$index],
        "Denumire" => $_POST["Denumire"][$index],
        "Moderatori" => $_POST["Moderatori"][$index],
        "Detalii" => $_POST["Detalii"][$index],
    );
}
```

After this you only have to iterate throught the $data array and execute paramtrized INSERT SQL commands.

- do not use old mysql lib
- learn about PDO and prepared statements

Comment: no i don't know the rest...

Answer (score 0):

I use this function:

```
        function InsertToTable($table, $data) {
            $total = count($data);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (";

            $runs = 0;
                foreach($data as $name => $value) {
                    $runs++;
                    $sql .= "`$name`";

                    if($runs != $total) {
                        $sql .= ',';
                    }
                }


            $sql .= ') VALUES(';

            $runs = 0;
                foreach($data as $name => $value) {
                    $runs++;
                    $sql .= "'$value'";

                    if($runs != $total) {
                        $sql .= ',';
                    }
                }

            $sql .= ')';

            if(mysql_query($sql)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And then you have an array with the data, like so:

```
            // columns to insert (array)
            // like this:
            // 'NAME_OF_FIELD_IN_TABLE' => 'CONTENT (i.e. the $_POST['field'] value)'
            $columnsToInsert = array(
                    $DataInterval1 => $_POST['DataInterval1'],
                    $Denumire1 => $_POST['Denumire1'],
                    $Moderatori1 => $_POST['Moderatori1'],
                );

            if(InsertToTable('tabel', $columnsToInsert)) {
                echo 'Hurray! Success';
            } else {
                echo 'An error happend :(';
            }
```

Hope it solves your question.

Comment: This is in conjunction with what Peter Kiss wrote?